# "The output of `ssh-add -l` doesn't contain 'RSA'. Start the agent, add your keys?" in Docker

Tags: macos, docker, ssh, docker-compose

I am following [this article](https://github.com/jpetazzo/orchestration-workshop/tree/master/prepare-vms) and have included my AWS credentials. I installed several CLI things required, and now get:

```
$ ./trainer start 5
Greetings, cchilders/cchilders!
The output of `ssh-add -l` doesn't contain 'RSA'. Start the agent, add your keys?
```

I have already did `eval $(ssh-agent)` which doesn't help.

Comment: Starting the agent is only the first step. You actually need to add keys to that agent.

Comment: That said, the question is off-topic here, as it isn't about software development as such -- SSH (and, by extension, `ssh-agent` and the keychain in general) is by no means "unique to software development", as described in http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Consider https://superuser.com/

Comment: (BTW, I'd also tend to suggest running `ssh-add -l` as a fairly obvious initial step to use to figure out what's going on when your system is in this state).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

```
ssh-add
```

...to actually add a key with the default name (`~/.ssh/id_rsa`) to your agent (assuming you've created a key; if you haven't you'll need to go back and do that). If you created a key saved with a different name, pass that name on the `ssh-add` command line.

That said, on MacOS X, you generally shouldn't start `ssh-agent` yourself at all! The keychain on OS X fulfils the agent protocol.

Comment: that worked. I didn't expect that because I already made ssh keys on `ssh-keygen` long ago. This describes what happened https://kb.iu.edu/d/aeww